# Using xPath in C# to get value of node attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xpath

If I have the following xml document:

```
<xml>
<data>
<dataset name="X"></dataset>
</data>
</xml>
```

How can I use Xpath in c# to retrieve the value of the name attribute (i.e. X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
xml/data/dataset/@name
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can I use Xpath in c# to retrieve the value of the name attribute
>   (i.e. X)

**This XPath expression**:

```
/xml/data/dataset/@name
```

selects the wanted attribute -- all atributes named `name` that belong to a `dataset` element that is a child of a `data` element that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**However, you want to get** *the value* **of the attribute -- not the node itself**.

**This XPath expression**:

```
string(/xml/data/dataset/@name)
```

**when evaluated, produces the wanted string value**.

In C# use the **[XPathNavigator.Evaluate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8.aspx)** method to evaluate the expression above.

Answer (score 0):

use this XPath expression:

```
xml/data/dataset
```

this will retrieve the dataset node. after that you can use C# tools to retrieve the attribute `name` from the node.

Comment: That ius fine if I know the path but not for dynamic xml content

Comment: then your question was misleading. if you only need to find elements which have `name` attribute in them, use `@name` path instead of the path i wrote above.